# Компилятор выдает ошибку на корректный код

Tags: c++

Доброе время суток, хеш код :-)

Имеется простой класс С++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class cSales      //  класс Стоимость
{
protected:
    enum {M = 3};
    float mSales [M];
public:
    void getdata();
    void putdata();
};

void cSales::getdata()
{ 
        //cin >> mSales[0];
        //cin >> mSales[1];
        //cin >> mSales[2];

    for (int i = 0, i < M , i++)
        cin >> mSales[i];   
}

void cSales::putdata()
{

    //cout << mSales[0] << ", " << mSales[1] << ", " << mSales[2] << endl;
    int i;
    for (i = 0, i < M, i++)
        cout << mSales[i] << ", ";  
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    cSales S1;
    S1.getdata();
    S1.putdata();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

MS VStudio 2010  выдает ошибки:

```
Ошибка  1   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие "," перед "<"    e:\программирование\мои проекты\упражнения от лафоре_2\9_3.cpp  50

Ошибка  2   error C2086: int i: переопределение e:\программирование\мои проекты\упражнения от лафоре_2\9_3.cpp  50

Ошибка  3   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед ")"    e:\программирование\мои проекты\упражнения от лафоре_2\9_3.cpp  59

Ошибка  4   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед ")"    e:\программирование\мои проекты\упражнения от лафоре_2\9_3.cpp  59
```

Что ему надо дать, чтобы он успокоился и скомпилил эти методы с циклами в теле? (без циклов нормально компилится и работает)

Спасибо заранее большое!!!

Answer (score 6):

У Вас :

```
for (int i = 0, i < M , i++)
```

А должно быть

```
for (int i = 0; i < M ; i++)
```

И т.д. Должны стоять  не запятые, а точки-с-запятой

Comment: Я уж начал гуглить новый стандарт на предмет запятых в форах =)

Comment: @1101_debian, плохо гуглите, новый стандарт запрещает объявлять переменную в `for`.

Comment: совсем не понял к чему ваш комментарий...

Comment: Спасибо, вот как ступил)) надо же))

Comment: Бывает )))

Comment: @1101_debian, это юмор такой. Типа шутка.